# rust: получить данные json с сайта

Tags: json, rust

Условный сайт `site.com` отдаёт данные в json, например, такие:

```
{
"a": {
    "text": ["abc", "xyz", "rty", "io", "f"], 
    "data": [
            [null, "txt", 18.1234, 12345678912345, -0.3]
            ]
     },
"b": {
    "text": ["qwe", "rty", "asd"], 
    "data": [
            [11343, 0, 20230407131355]
            ]
     }
}
```

хочу их получить, чтобы потом сохранить в базе postgresql одной записью в формате json.
Пробую http-client `reqwest` и по ходу потребовался `serde`:

```
[dependencies]
reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["json"] }
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
serde = { version = "1.0.159", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
```

`main.rs`:

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Msg {
    a: A,
    b: B,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct A {
    text: Vec<String>,
    data: Vec<Vec<Option<Datum>>>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct B {
    text: Vec<String>,
    data: Vec<Vec<i64>>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Datum {
    Double(f64),
    String(String),
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
      // ...
      let resp = reqwest::get("https://site.com")
                 .await?.json::<Msg>().await?;
      // ...
      println!("{:?}", resp);   

Ok(())
}
```

`println!` выводит не то, как ожидаю, а типа такого:

```
Msg { a: A { text: ["abc", "xyz", ...

             data: [[None, Some(String("txt")), Some(Double(18.1234), Some(Double(12345678912345.0)), Some(Double(-0.3))]]
```

надо так:

```
Msg { "a": { "text": ["abc", "xyz", ...
             "data": [[null, "txt", 18.1234, 12345678912345, -0.3]]
```

а лучше без `Msg`, чтоб как оригинал:

```
{
"a": {
    "text": ["abc", "xyz", "rty", "io", "f"], 
    "data": [
            [null, "txt", 18.1234, 12345678912345, -0.3]
            ]
     },
"b": {
    "text": ["qwe", "rty", "asd"], 
    "data": [
            [11343, 0, 20230407131355]
            ]
     }
}
```

Как получить правильно, чтобы `a` и `text` в кавычках, без `A` без `Some(String ... Double` и целыми числами?

Comment: C PHP или Java видимо пришли, раз null-ы хотите, однако, в Rust нет такого типа, однако, имеется структура Result, которая в себе содержит None, если значение было неполучено и Some, т.е. обертка над некоторым значением, т.к. Rust компилятор должен при компиляции знать типы данных и их объем. Более подробно, как извечь значения из типа Result и обработать None/Some тут: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/

Comment: Если делаю ``let j = serde_json::to_string(&resp)?;`` то получу ``null``  так: ``println!("{:?}", j);`` только ``12345678912345.0``  выводит вместо целых ``12345678912345`` Можно получить строку и сделать так: ``let m: Msg = serde_json::from_str(&j)?;`` Думаю, надо править мою структуру, чтобы вынимать целые числа тоже.

Comment: @Borislav, у Вас есть рабочий вариант решения? Чтобы было максимально быстро. Приведите, пожалуйста, я его отмечу.

Comment: @Borislav, [Option](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как ни странно, `json::<Msg>().await` означает: "Десериализуй из JSON в объект типа `Msg`". То есть JSON у вас на руках не оказывается, а вместо него - сразу настоящая rust-структура (имплементация трейта Debug `{:?}` которой не претендует на совместимость с JSON). Потому тут есть два путя:

1. Не десериализовывать тело, а вытащить его как текст, получив всамделешний JSON в виде строки:

```rust
let resp = reqwest::get("https://site.com").await?
                      .text().await?;
```

Потом, когда это будет необходимо, строку можно десериализовать в объект (`let msg = serde_json::from_str::<Msg>(&resp)?;`)

2. Вручную сериализовать `Msg` обратно в JSON там, где вам это необходимо:

```rust
println!("{}", &serde_json::to_string(&resp)?);
```

Comment: спасибо. Думал, что если сайт отдаёт json и мне он нужен, чтобы сохранить целиком в базе, как тип json, то `.json::<Msg>().await? ` как бы нативный вариант. Т.к. нужно максимально быстро. Чем он тогда лучше, чем text() и что быстрей? У меня с числами: ``12345678912345.0`` вместо ``12345678912345`` выводит. Если положение переменных постоянно, то править структуру?

Comment: Просто скопировать строку (`text`) дешевле, чем парсить ее (`json`). Если не нужно как-либо изменять или валидировать JSON, то можно прямо в виде строки текста его и передавать сразу в базу, туда-сюда конвертировать смысла нет.

Comment: А так, JSON - это особым образом сформированный текст, когда речь идет про копирование "как есть", так что `text` вполне подойдет.